# Белый экран смерти в yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, nginx

Всем привет! Мне кажется, моё приложение сошло с ума. Периодически на определенных страницах моего приложения выбрасывает белый экран, вместо страницы, исходный код абсолютно пуст, причем белый экран иногда сменяется 502 bad gateway, включил в yii отображение всех ошибок, index.php

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

Белый экран пропадает и выводятся Notice ошибки, фатальных ошибок нет. Причем что самое странное после перезагрузки сервера все становится нормально, белый экран перестает появляться. Когда я пытаюсь перейти на страницу с белым экраном, кликнув по ссылке, то на странице вообще ничего не происходит, страницы как бы подвисает, появляется курсор навигации по тексту (I), браузер через какое то время говорит, что страницу загрузить не удалось. Я даже не знаю в какую сторону копать и что делать, кроме как перегружать сервер... может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? В какую сторону копать?

```
nginx/1.6.3
PHP 5.5.30
```

Comment: Что делать? Поставить нормальный дебагер и не парить себе и другим мозг!

Comment: логи сервера в студию. как минимум от нотайсов избавиться и варнингов

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); ?

Comment: php-fpm работает на unix сокете или tcp?

Comment: Может у вас что-то вошло в бесконечный loop. Или БД залочилась? Плавающий баг, где-то что-то переопределяете или по указателю передаете?

Answer (score 2):

Включите в настройкаъ php логгирование ошибок.

В рантайме можно сделать так:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "path/to/php-error.log");
```

Посмотрите на логи, которые пишет framework, в папку runtime/logs/, изучите логи, исправьте ошибки и "экран смерти" пропадёт.

P.S.: В Yii2 уставновите деббагер - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug , но не используйте его на продакшене.